# How do I lock a sheet in Google Sheets at a specific time every day?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I would like the sheet protected from 6pm - 10pm every day. I have the following script but it doesn't seem to protect the sheet at the designated time. I have this script with the Time-based trigger, day, 6-10pm. Any help fixing this script is appreciated.

```
function protectAll() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].protect().setDescription("Temporary protection");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, You're looking for something like [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

So, there are at least two options for Your case:

1. Manual setup, which does not seam very versatile, but You can setup a call of particular functions at hour length window every day -  **Edit > Current project's triggers > Create new trigger**
2. Programmatically, using something like following:

```
  function setup_triggers() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("protectAll")
          .timeBased()
          .atHour(18)
          .everyDays(1)
          .create();

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("unprotectAll")
          .timeBased()
          .atHour(22)
          .everyDays(1)
          .create();
  }
```

Beware that the trigger will be executed according to the timezone of the script (not sure what exactly does in mean in the context of Apps Script).

EDIT: right, apparently You could [specify timezone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#inTimezone(String)) as well. As far official example goes, it would be something like following:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("protectAll")
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(18)
      .everyDays(1)
      .inTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")
      .create();
```